# Querying Sharepoint document in Graph API by web url

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm developping an application that aims to work with java and should allow crud operations on files.
I do have an update functionnality that has to work with a library containing more than 5000 documents.

My goal is to retrieve a specific document based on its path. for this I use the property webUrl.

I do make an API call to the following URL

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items?expand=fields,driveItem&$query=webUrl eq 'https://{sharepointUrl}/sites/{siteName} /{listName}/fileName.PDF'
```

Apparently, i do retrieve all the documents contained in the library. Previously, in a context where i had less than 5000 documents, I could use fields/fileLeafRef.

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter item by `webUrl`.

Could you use [shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint in your case?

```
GET /shares/{shareIdOrEncodedSharingUrl}
GET /shares/{shareIdOrEncodedSharingUrl}/driveItem
GET /shares/{shareIdOrEncodedSharingUrl}/listItem
```

You need to [transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#encoding-sharing-urls) the web URL into a sharing token.

Java code:

```
String webUrl = "https://{sharepointUrl}/sites/{siteName}/{listName}/fileName.PDF";
byte[] byteData = webUrl.getBytes();
String base64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteData);
String encodedUrl = "u!"+base64String.replace("=","").replace('/','_').replace('+','_');
```

Then call shares endpoint

```
GET /shares/{encodedUrl}
GET /shares/{encodedUrl}/driveItem
GET /shares/{encodedUrl}/listItem
```